# Validate email with database

Tags: php, database, authentication

I have created a form and have validated everything using PHP, but can't figure out how to validate email from database. If I have the entered username in the database, I want it to display an error. I have connect.php and

just for an example -

here's how i validate password -

```
if(!empty($_POST['password']))
{
 if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['cpass']) 
 {
  $errors[] = 'The password and confirm password do not match.';
 }
 else
 {
  $p=trim($_POST['password']);
 }
}
```

here is what i'm trying to do -

```
$getusername = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE ($u,$username)";
if($getusername)
{
    echo 'Username is already in use.';
}
else
{
    $g=trim($_POST['username']);
```

}

THIS RESULTS IN A PARSE ERROR.

Comment: Do you know how to run a SELECT query with WHERE statement?

Comment: Please reword your question. Very hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: i do know how to run select with where...what next?

Comment: Umm run a select against the username and/or email. if it results a result then its valid, if not then its not valid. Now dependinr on how you use each of these things it may be more complicated than that but thats the basic idea... which is about all you can get with the info youve given us. Also somewhat unrealted... you should be hashing and salting those passwords which it doesnt seem like youre doing if youre pulling them right out of `$_POST`.

Comment: @alin yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what next? just run it. if a query will return a row - there is such a name already. if no rows - the name is free, proceed with registration

Comment: And what is it you want to verify? Username, password or an email address?

Comment: THANK YOUA LL, WITH ALEC'S HELP, IT WORKED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first define the username from the $_POST variable
// make sure to escape the value to prevent SQL injection
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));

// select a user with the posted username
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";

// run the query
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// see if there's a result
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
  echo 'This username is already taken';
} else {
  // .. do stuff
}
```

Comment: As I am a beginner, could you explain why u used LIMIT 1? Thanks.

Comment: There are various ways [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) can be used, but in this case the idea is that the query can be aborted when a single result has been found. Since we're looking for possible duplicates, a single result would already be enough for us to determine that there _is_ a dupe; there's no point in searching any further. In this case it probably won't make much of a difference in speed, but if you're searching through a huge list of records, it might make a difference.

Comment: @Johnson I advise you to google the simeple things like "What LIMIT is for in mysql and you may save time & energy and maybe also learn new things from mysql documentation"